# Can't Connect with Windows Network

Tags: release-freya

I am trying to connect my windows 8 with freya to share files. But its showing some error like this. There in my windows 8 I turned on sharing and its ready to connect.

[image]

Help me to fix it and share files from Windows to Freya

Comment: No i am trying to connect  through " entire Network" option  with another lap which is windows 8